# Why does my Yongnuo YN-685 freeze with my YN-622-TX?

Tags: troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, yongnuo

I have a Canon 77D, a Yongnuo 622-TX controller on top of the camera, and a YN622C transceiver with a YN-568EX II speedlight.

This system works perfectly.

Yesterday I bought a YN-685. The problem is that it freezes after 1-5 pops when triggered from the YN622-TX attached to the camera. I went to the local dealership and we tried it together. We tested it with a different YN622-TX attached to my camera and it worked, but it's still freezing when I try it with *my* YN622-TX. I have tried the latest firmware update but didn't solve it. I also don't have a guarantee for the YN622-TX.

Could anyone tell me what is the best way to trigger both of my flashes off-camera? I don't know how to connect them as master and slave.

Comment: What is the date code inside the battery cover of your YN622-TX?

Comment: How are you using the flashes? TTL, manual, or mixed? What exposure mode are you using? Av? M? P? Auto?

Comment: Have you confirmed the firmware update "took?" Does the latest firmware version display when you pull it up on the YN622-TX's menu?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem. My 622 tx had the latest firmware update, I just updated with the same version :)

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone tell me what is the best way to trigger both of my flashes off-camera?

If the newer YN622-TX at the store works correctly and your older YN622-YX with the latest firmware loaded doesn't, the obvious solution is to buy the newer YN622-TX. They're only about $40 online.